# Intersection theory on normal crossing algebraic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be an algebraic surface with normal crossing singularities. Suppose the singular locus of $X$ is a smooth curve. Let us denote it by $C$. Suppose $D$ is another smooth curve in $X$ which intersects with $C$ at a point. Assume that the intersection is transversal in the local irreducible component of $X$ which contains both the curves.

My questions are :

1. Can we properly define the topological intersection number of $C$ and $D$ in $X$?
2. Can we properly define the algebraic intersection number of $C$ and $D$ in $X$? If yes, in that case is the intersection number always positive?
3. Are these two intersection numbers equal?

Comment: What do you mean by "can we properly define"?

Comment: @Sasha  Is there a notion that satisfies the usual properties of the intersection number? namely positivity, vanishing and additivity. At least positivity.

Comment: On any scheme you can intersect any curve with a Cartier divisor. Your curve $D$ is a Cartier divisor, so you can use this version of the intersection product.

Comment: @Sasha will you please explain why is D a Cartier divisor? it is not clear to me why is it a Cartier divisor in the local ring of the intersection point of D with C.

Comment: Etale locally the surface is k[x,y,z]/xy, the curve C is given by the ideal (x,y) and the curve D is given by, for example, the ideal (z, x) or (z, y).

Comment: It wasn't clear from the description given in the question what do you precisely mean by $D$, so my guess was wrong. Of course, the curve given by $(z, x)$ is not a Cartier divisor.

Comment: @Sasha ok, but following what you said, we still can take dual of the ideal sheaf of C and restrict to D and define the intersection number as the degree of this sheaf.

Comment: You can, of course. The question is what do you expect from the obtained number.

Comment: @Sasha thank you. I just expect the following: if C is algebraically equivalent to C' in X, then [C] . [D]= [C'] . [D]. For example, if C is algebraically equivalent to 0 in X, then C. D=0. This is true if X is smooth. But for me X has normal crossing singularities.